# Why filter criteria not filtering any thing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code, which is working but it is not filtering any data. Just throwing header row in the mail.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim xAddress As String
Dim a As String


With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "ME@ME.COM"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .htmlbody = "Hi All" & "<br>"
For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
    a = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value Like "GBL?*" Then
        Set Rng = Nothing
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & a & Chr(9) & "Projects" & RangetoHTML(Range("A1:H78")) & "<br>"
    End If
Next i
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & a, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set Rng = Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
Rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , True, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , True, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

The current output is as shown here

[image]

however the expected output should be having tables like this

[image]

under each project name.

Why it is not taking criteria 1 as cell value correctly?

Comment: I am not able to change the second image link which is missing "g" from "jpg" extension. Please add this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the variable `a` is assigned in the `Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body` with `a = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value`.

However, in `RangeToHtml` it is used here - `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & a, Operator:=xlFilterValues`, but it is not assigned to anything. The scope of the variable is only in the `Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body` Thus, the criteria does not work.

---

What should be done?

- use `Option Explicit` to avoid usage of undeclared variables. The VBEditor would tell immediately once something is not declared;
- make sure to name the variables properly. `a` is not a good name;
- try to debug and to see the values of the variables. Debugging is done step-by-step with <kbd>F8</kbd> and `Debug.Print a` would help you, to see the current value;
- try to write some kind of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), just for yourself, using as less code as possible. Then probably the debugging would be easier.

Comment: @KeshavSharma - you are welcome. Take a look here and consider selecting the answer as accepted - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I am not able to up-vote your answer dear, but I've accepted it.